# playing a video from lists of vlcj player

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to play a video from the lists of MRL provided as a String.

The problem is when I run the class, a list of panels shows with play button and a black screen, but only the last panel plays one video, out of the lists of videos, and when the play buttons of other panel is clicked, the last video replays again.

What I want to achieve is, when I run the class, a single video plays, and when I click on the play button of another video, the current video stops and moves to the next video.

I don't know where I have gone wrong.

As for vlcj, i tried user other layout, but the video shows only when BorderLayout is used, which has limited my options

Here is my code:

```
public class MediaPlayer2 extends JPanel {

//Declares our media player component
private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaplayer;
private final String vlcpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC";
private JPanel video_pnl, control_pnl;
private JButton play_btn;
ArrayList<String> file_location;

public MediaPlayer2(ArrayList<String> file_location) {
    this.file_location = file_location;
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcpath);

    int increment = 0;
    while (increment < file_location.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            video_pnl = new JPanel();
            video_pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            play_btn = new JButton("Play");
            mediaplayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
            control_pnl = new JPanel();
            control_pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            play_btn.setActionCommand("play");
            video_pnl.add(mediaplayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            control_pnl.add(play_btn);
            video_pnl.add(control_pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            play_btn.addActionListener(handler);
        }
        add(video_pnl);
        increment++;
    }
}

private class Handler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("play")) {
            play();
        }
    }
}

public void play() {
    for (int i = 0; i < file_location.size(); i++) {
        mediaplayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(file_location.get(i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare and initialize local variables
    ArrayList<String> file_location = new ArrayList<>();
    file_location.add("C:\\\\Users\\\\goldAnthony\\\\Desktop\\\\Videos\\\\Whistle.mp4");
    file_location.add("C:\\\\Users\\\\goldAnthony\\\\Desktop\\\\Videos\\\\Beyonce_Hello.mp4");
    file_location.add("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Desktop\\Videos\\HansRosling_2012S_480p.mp4");
    file_location.add("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Desktop\\Videos\\oow2010_2.mp4");
    file_location.add("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Desktop\\Videos\\The_Economic_Environment.mp4");

    //creates instances of the VlcPlayer object, pass the mediaPath and invokes the method "run"
    MediaPlayer2 mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer2(file_location);
    JFrame ourframe = new JFrame();
    ourframe.setContentPane(mediaplayer);
    ourframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    ourframe.setSize(300, 560);
    ourframe.setVisible(true);
    mediaplayer.play();
    ourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is this necessary for some reason?

Comment: @nachokk, yah in each panel there is one video player and one button

Comment: and what is the difference having that `for` or not, it's useless.. only executes one time.

Comment: @nachokk, yah i just removed it, there is no need for the for loop. Although, can you help me work out the main problem dough. Thanks

Comment: Well actually your question is very similar to this one , [playing a video from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760900/playing-a-video-from-an-array-of-vlcj-player)

Comment: @rachokk, i posted that same quaestion, but i found out that i could make have multiple panels, buttons and video player without the need of arrays, which is more efficient. But i still have the same problem, which is only one video playing from the lists of mrl provided.